# celda de TABLA excel con lista desplegable no muestra flecha indicadora

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Tengo lista de datos con A1 a1 D1 encabezados. quiero cargar datos a partir de fila 2, con lista desplegable en columna A, el origen de la lista está en otro rango, funciona todo perfecto.

Ahora bien, cuando transformo la lista de datos en tabla excel 2013, me valida el ingreso pero no me muestra la flecha de la lista para elegir opciones.

Les agradeceré me orienten como proceder para tener una tabla excel y un ingreso de datos validados, que se vea la lista desplegable dentro de la celda de la tabla

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un pantallazo? No solo de la celda, sino de la configuración de la validación de datos. O si puedes compartir el archivo para ver si es algo de versiones, sería mejor

Answer (score 2):

No sé si puede audarte, pero acabo de probar con el Excel 2019 y he podido crear una tabla con las celdas en la columna A con validaciones. Te dejo na imagen de como me ha quedado:

[image: Imágen]

A lo mejor es cuestión de versiones porque la verdad que con el 2019 no he tenido ningún problema en hacerlo.

Espero te sirva. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Al configurar la validación, es necesario indicar que las celdas deben tener lista desplegable.

Puedes editar la validación seleccionado cualquiera de las celdas del rango que ya tienen la validación, luego en la ficha datos da click en "Validación de datos" y activa la casilla "Celda con lista desplegable", click en aceptar.

[image: Validación de datos con lista desplegable]